# Function does not run ok in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, xui

I've got this jQuery, javascript, xui function that is running ok in Chrome and Firefox but it doesn't work as expected in Safari.
What I'm trying to do is clear checkboxes in a group when one of them is check, just to have only one checkbox checked at the same time.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 <?php
    foreach($qOptions as $qOption) { ?>
        function fclearlistboxQ<?php echo $qOption->question_id . "_QO" . $qOption->id; ?>() {
            <?php if($qOption->question->multiple == 0){ ?>
            clearListBoxInputs("div#divQ<?php echo $qOption->question_id; ?>","Q<?php echo $qOption->question_id . "_QO" . $qOption->id; ?>");
            <?php } ?>
        }
        x$("input#Q<?php echo $qOption->question_id . "_QO" . $qOption->id; ?>").click(fclearlistboxQ<?php echo $qOption->question_id . "_QO" . $qOption->id; ?>);
        appendToTrigger('fclearlistboxQ<?php echo $qOption->question_id . "_QO" . $qOption->id; ?>');

<?php }?>

function clearListBoxInputs(divelement,selected) {
    x$(divelement).find("input").each(function(element, index, xui) {
        if(element.name != selected) {
            x$(element).filter(function () {
                return this.checked;
            }).each(function (element, index, xui) {
                    element.checked = false;
            });
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't use radio buttons rather than checkboxes, which only allow one to be checked at a time?

Comment: My boss prefers checkboxes... There's no other reason...

Comment: That's a severe user experience problem.

Comment: Not sure if it's a good idea to use XUI. I was looking for their home page, and they seem to have let their domain registration lapse.

Comment: Boss should stop trying to re-invent web forms